# connection string with no user name and password, asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2000, connection-string

i have a website built in asp.net connecting to a sql 2000 db. within my web.config file, i have a connection string referencing a DSN. in order for my db connection to work i have to include the username and password within the string.  for security reasons, is there any way to connect to my db without displaying the username and password. maybe a method to encrypt the information?? the trusted connection string method did not work for me.

current method

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

trusted method (did not work in my server environment)

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

Comment: Why didn't the trusted connection work? Did you get a login failure or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can encrypt connection strings in your web.config file.

See [How To: Secure Connection Strings When Using Data Source Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dx0f3cf2%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: Good one. You can also (as a further step) restrict access to config files for all users except the asp user (and admins perhaps).

Answer (score 0):

**For MySQL with port number**

`<add name="constring" connectionString="Server=localhost;Uid=root;Database=databasename;Port=3306;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>`